# Using RegQueryInfoKey

Tags: c++, registry

I am new to programming, I would like to know the number of entries in a registry key. I think entries are called subkeys but I am not sure. I am trying to use RegQueryInfoKey() but I don't fully understand the MSDN webpage since I am beginner.

```
HKEY hKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
char regpath[] = "SOFTWARE\\MyApplication\\"
LPDWORD numberofEntries;
RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, regpath, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
RegQueryInfoKey(hKey, NULL, NULL, NULL, numberofEntries, NULL);
```

then I would like to printf the number of entries in this key. The code above doesn't work, the app crash.

How is it done?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[`RegQueryInfoKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724902%28VS.85%29.aspx) has 12 parameters. You are only passing 6. I can't understand how that even compiles—perhaps you are providing your own definition of `RegQueryInfoKey` rather than the one from the windows header files.

Perhaps you are getting confused by the fact that many of the parameters to `RegQueryInfoKey` are marked as optional. This only means that you can pass `NULL` into the function and not that you can omit the parameters altogether.

Comment: App crash == doesn't compile.  Only thing that makes sense.